# Change the icon of an executable file from command line

Tags: kde, icons

I want to change the icon image of the executable files **from the command line**. I'm using KDE.

Comment: This might prove to be DE-specific.  What's your desktop?

Comment: i am using KDE.

Comment: I do not believe "executables" have icons, but I could be wrong. Generally this is faked with various .ini files.

Comment: What version of KDE? The answer may be different for KDE 3 and 4.

Answer (score 2):

In KDE4 you have to create file **~/.local/share/mime/packages/application-x-executable.xml** with such content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mime-info xmlns="http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info">
    <mime-type type="application/x-executable">
        <comment>executable</comment>
        <icon name="application-x-executable"/>
        <glob-deleteall/>
    </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

Then you can change the *icon name* value to something built-in like "**emblem-favorite**" or specify the full path: "**/home/my_user/my_ico/my_exec.png**". After saving the file, run `update-mime-database ~/.local/share/mime/`. The changes will apply almost immidiately.